# How to automate testing a user journey?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I use NodeJS for the web server and Mocha for testing. I tried this test to ensure that the application can create a user, log it out, and sign it in again:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

const req = request(app);

describe("user journey", function() {
  it("tests a user journey (signup, logout, sign in)", function(done) {
    let signedInStub = "something only for logged in users";
    req
      .post("/signup")
      .send({
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "password": "abcd1234"
      })
      .expect(function(response) {
        expect(response.body.includes(signedInStub))
      })
      .get("/logout")
      .expect(function(response) { // <-- Test fails here.
        !response.body.includes(signedInStub)
      })
      .post("/login")
      .send({
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "password": "abcd1234"
      })
      .expect(function(response) {
        response.body.includes(signedInStub)
      })
      .get("/content/2")
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

I run it with `mocha --exit test.js` and get the error:

```
  1) user journey
       tests a user journey (signup, logout, sign in):
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'expect' of undefined
```

How can I test on the command-line that a user can create an account, log out, and log in?

Comment: Is this using supertest? I don't believe it can chain multiple requests that way.

Comment: Yes, it's using supertest, and I updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [`agent`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/8b1a1d878ba460f1ef9b433e377f1623e90915b6/test/supertest.js#L836) and use that across multiple requests to persist the session.

If needed, install `chai`, which works with `supertest`, with `npm install --save chai`. (See [here](https://livecodestream.dev/post/2020-08-17-testing-in-nodejs-using-mocha-and-chai-part-1/) for details about testing in NodeJS with Mocha and Chai.)

If you are using an auth type other than cookies, persist the data in a variable in the same way and send it with each request.

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

const { expect } = require('chai')

const User = require('../models/user');
const email = "test@test.com";

describe("user journey", function() {

  let req
  let signedInStub = "something only for logged in users"

  before(function(){
    req = request.agent(app)
  })

  it("should signup a new test@test.com user", async function() {

    // Delete this email in case emails are unique in the database.
    await User.deleteOne({email: email});

    const response = await req.post("/signup")
      .send({
        "email": email,
        "password": "abcd1234"
      })
      .redirects(1); // optional, in case your back-end code uses a redirect after signing up.
    // Log the response so you can track errors, e.g. hidden parameters in the HTML form that are missing from this POST request in code.
    console.log(response.text);
    expect(response.text).to.include(signedInStub)
  })

  it("should logout the new user", async function() {
    const response = await req.get("/logout")
    expect(response.text).not.to.include(signedInStub)
  })

  it("should login the new user", async function() {
    const response = await req.post("/login")
      .send({
        "email": email,
        "password": "abcd1234"
      })
    expect(response.text).to.include(signedInStub)
  })

  it("should get the new users content", async function() {
    await req.get("/content/2")
      .expect(200)
  });
});
```

Comment: I am getting `AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given` in the first three tests, and `Error: expected 200 "OK", got 302 "Found"` in the last one, because I redirect to 404 in case of a user not logged in instead of rendering the template. And now, the testing thread now does not terminate, I need to stop it with `Ctl-C`, why is that?

Comment: Not existing is usually something maintaining a connection, like a database or maybe the agent to the app. `mocha -e` will forcefully quit but you can normally use a `after` function to close/disconnect things.

Comment: And check what `response` and `response.body` are being set to for those tests.

Comment: I added `console.log(response);` after the `expect()` and I saw nothing in the console. The reason is that the test was failing and throwing an error before that line, so I edited the question to log the response before the failing assertion.

Comment: Now I know why the tests kept a stale connection: I started running tests from the scripts with `mocha` without the `--exit`. Because the testing function is `async`, I find it more robust to exit from the command-line than repeating the code that connects to Mongoose from the NodeJS app (e.g., `const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const connectRetry = function() { mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db", { ... })};`.

Comment: The reason for the error `AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given` is that the original answer was using `response.body`, which is an empty object, and the HTML is in `response.text`. I edited the answer to fix this and added logging of the response to track other errors.